# Fixed position issue and z-index: how to make a child of a sticky element "on top" of a (unrelated) fixed element?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is placing the `<button>` element on top of the `<div>` element and, at the same time, place the `<nav>` behind the `<div>`. In other words, anything but the `<button>` should be visible.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DW91IdO9dL

1. A sticky `<nav>` element with `position: sticky`
2. The `<nav>` has a `<button>` child with `position: relative; z-index: 30`
3. A `<div>` element with `position: fixed; z-index: 20`

Of course, this isn't working, `<button>` isn't visible at all, despite the greater `z-index`. I guess because the `<nav>` crate a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Setting a z-index: 30 on the `<nav>` itself would show the `<button>`, but also other `<nav>` elements and its background color:

[image: fixed position issue]

This is the HTML structure, but I can change as I wish (place the `<div>` before/after):

```html
<nav style="position: sticky">
  <button style="position: relative; z-index: 30"></button>
</nav>

<div style="position: fixed: z-index: 20"></div>
```

Comment: This won't work, because children inherit the stacking order of their parents - see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991878/z-index-not-working-as-expected-text-showing-under-blocks]

Comment: read until the end of the duplicate to find ideas of solution

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. What I would suggest is to have the nav set with no background color or z-index. Add another div to your nav and use that as a background color. You can then set the z-index of every element in the nav set lower than the div. But set the button's index higher.

Edit: Here's a working example:
https://codepen.io/kenjibailly/pen/wvyNYqx

HTML:


✕

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

nav > div:last-child {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
}

nav + div {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

This has already been answered here in a different but similar context:
[can I override z-index inheritance from parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198947/can-i-override-z-index-inheritance-from-parent-element)

Comment: Won't work. Removed z-index from nav, set z-index 30 on button... and other elements to a lower z-index.

Comment: @gremo I added a working example in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, but still need a z-index for the nav. The concept is: nav is above body (say z-index: 10), div is above nav (say z-index: 20). Button inside nav should be above div. Isn't that possible, right?

Comment: @gremo That's not possible as the button will be relative to the nav's z-index.